# What is the statistical significance of pandas describe function and how to use it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a data frame which show some information like count, mean, std and some percentiles. Can you please explain how actually one uses this data to understand a df/a series.

```
          losses       wins         year
count   8.000000   8.000000     8.000000
mean    6.625000   9.375000  2011.125000
std     3.377975   3.377975     0.834523
min     1.000000   4.000000  2010.000000
25%     5.000000   7.500000  2010.750000
50%     6.000000  10.000000  2011.000000
75%     8.500000  11.000000  2012.000000
```

Can someone please explain how each one of count, mean, std, min,.& those percentiles are used for understanding data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are a few statistics that give some perspective on the nature of the distribution of the data.

- `mean` is the average and is the "expected" value of the distribution.  On average, you'd expect to get this number.
- `std` tells you how big of swings the data takes relative to the `mean`.  Specifically, its the `mean` squared deviation from the `mean`.
- `50%` is also the median and it's difference from the `mean` gives information on the skew of the distribution.  It's also another definition of average that is robust to outliers in the data.
- `25%` & `75%` give perspective on the kurtosis.  Also, all percentile numbers are generally more robust to outliers.
- `min`, `max`, `max - min`, `75% - 25%` are all alternatives to perspectives on how big of swings the data takes relative to the `mean`
- `count` the larger this number, the more credibility all the stats have.